# c++ bool anomaly -- why is this possible?

Tags: c++, language-features

I just stumbled across this: When postifix incrementing a bool twice, the integer value still is 1 instead of the expected 2. I'd like to know why this happens.

```
bool test = false; // results in integer 0
test++; // results in integer 1
test++; // results in integer 1

// but there still is at least one byte of memory used:
// results in integer 137
*(unsigned char*)(&test) = 137;
```

Comment: Without looking at any machine code produced by this, I would assume that the compiler ignores all but the least significant *bit* when you've told it to work on a `bool`.  It's also possible that `bool + 1` gets turned into `bool & 1` as an optimization or to prevent overflows, which would cause the behavior you're seeing. The compiler could be doing some even more clever; you should really include the assembly for this bit of code.

Comment: A `bool` can only be either `true` or `false`, setting it to 137 is undefined behavior

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how the `++` operator is specified.  See C++11 §5.2.6[expr.post.incr]/1 (emphasis mine):

> The value of a postfix `++` expression is the value of its operand.  [Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value —end note] The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a complete object type.
>
> The value of the operand object is modified by adding 1 to it, **unless the object is of type bool, in which case it is set to true.** [Note: this use is deprecated, see Annex D. —end note]

(The prefix `++` operator has similar language to allow it to be applied to a `bool` value.)

Modifying the `bool` object through a pointer or reference of a type other than `bool` yields undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm guessing applying `--` to a `bool` would set it to `false`, then, regardless of its prior state?

Comment: @JAB:  No.  Neither the prefix nor the postfix `--` may be applied to an operand of type `bool`.

Comment: Aliasing through `unsigned char` is allowed, though. The UB doesn't come from just modifying it, it comes from writing a value not in the value representation of `bool`. This is fine: `bool d, s = true; std::memcpy(&d, &s, sizeof(bool)); /* loop char by char */` for example.

Answer (score 0):

> why is this possible?!

Undefined behaviour is just that - undefined.  Anything at all could happen.

> if enough memory for `137` is allocated, then why the hell `test++`; results in `1`?

The language specification defines that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've invoked undefined behavior by casting a pointer to a different type and performing read/write on it.  UB = anything can happen, including nasal demons.